# XSD.EXE - Generating classes from XSD file fails giving strange warnings

Tags: .net, xml, windows, soap, xsd

I am trying to generate .Net classes from the [CWMP 1.1 XSD file](https://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-1.xsd), for use in a client. To generate the classes I used the XSD.EXE utility from the Windows SDK but I get errors:

- multiple instances of `Undefined complexType 'http://schmeas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is used as a base for complex Type restricition'`
- one `The
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:mustUnderstand' attribute is not
  declared.`

I checked and both of the urls are valid. This baffles me.

---

I tried using the xsd2code command line tool, but I'm having an hard time adding items to SOAP arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can repeat your error but, like you, I cant see the reason.

I've often has trouble with xsd.exe in the past. So much so that last year I switched to xsd2code++ (http://www.xsd2code.com/en-us/home.aspx) and never looked back since.  Xsd2code++ will produce more compact code and give you greater control over what it produces.  I tested the CWMP xsd with it and it works a dream.